# Socket Programming in C - How can I change my IP?

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, webserver

I would like to know how it is possible to change my IP address in C. Suppose I have a server that I want to connect to in C with the functions socket(), bind(), listen(), accept(), receive() and send(). Is it possible to change the IP address of my computer when connecting to the server?

I want to change it so that when I go to the internet and type "what is my ip" into the search engine, it brings up the IP address that I am connected to C. Is this possible? If so, is there any source code on this for me to study? I don't want to just copy and paste, I want to understand and know how this works.

Comment: If you are connected to the Internet through a retail ISP service, such as a fiber or cable company, and you have a cable modem or similar device connected to that service, then the IP address that appears in a “What is my IP” web site is the IP address of that device, and that IP address is assigned by your ISP and cannot be changed by you. Inside your home or company network, you can set up your own internal IP address assignments (often in a network router, such as a Wi-Fi router). Those will not be visible to the outside network. This would be done through the router interface, not C code.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In general, you can't change your address on the public Internet, it's assigned by your ISP.

Comment: I just want to know how to write a VPN connection in C. Maybe need IPTABLES commands? The TOR Network is also written in C, so it is 100% possible to change IP addresses using C, I just don't know how.

Comment: Another question is how to connect to a VPN using bridges? I'm thinking obfs4 or snowflake. in /etc/tor/torrc, if you set up a bridge and I connect to a VPN, can it work by connecting to the bridge first and then to the VPN?

Comment: anyway, thanks for the answers! :DD hope you are very well.